# how do I "merge" all these boxplots into one single boxplot for values >0

Tags: r

my data set contains 18 variables, 2 of them being PM2.5 and rain, the rain variable takes values from 0 to 20, how do I make a single boxplot of PM2.5 against rain for all values of rain > 0 instead of multiple different boxplots for each value that rain takes. This is the code for the boxplots

```
> boxplot(PM2.5~RAIN, subset(data, RAIN > 0 & hour==12))
```

a picture of the boxplots
[image]

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boxplot(data[(data$RAIN > 0) & (data$hour == 12), 'PM2.5'])`